# Pivot a dataframe keeping all the columns and assigning suffixes and values to each column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have searched across SO and the internet but the closest I have gotten to my answer is that I may need to implement df.pivot(). However I can't seem to figure out what should I pass in the values and columns parameters in order to achieve the expected result.

Initial dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(

{'Date': ['8-Sep-22',
  '8-Sep-22',
  '8-Sep-22',
  '8-Sep-22',
  '16-Jun-22',
  '16-Jun-22',
  '27-Apr-22',
  '27-Apr-22'],
 'CLASS': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
 'CCY': ['USD', 'USD', 'USD', 'USD', 'USD', 'USD', 'USD', 'USD'],
 'SZE(M)': [202.81, 13.78, 13.39, 9.1, 356.0, 15.45, 405.62, 27.56],
 'WAL': ['1.91', '-', '-', '2.25', '1.05', '3.19', '2.28', '2.58'],
 'DR': ['AAA', 'AA', 'A', 'BBB', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'AAA', 'AA'],
 'TYPE': ['Fixed',
  'Fixed',
  'Fixed',
  'Fixed',
  'Fixed',
  'Fixed',
  'Fixed',
  'Fixed'],
 'BNCH': ['I-Curve',
  'I-Curve',
  'I-Curve',
  'I-Curve',
  'I-Curve',
  'I-Curve',
  'I-Curve',
  'I-Curve'],
 'GDNC': ['225-235', '275a', '325a', '450a', '-', '-', '175a', '200a'],
 'SPRD': ['215', '290', '330', '450', '275', '-', '170', '200'],
 'CPN': ['4.30%', '4.64%', '4.89%', '5.53%', '4.55%', '-', '4.30%', '4.64%'],
 'YLD': ['5.65%', '6.40%', '6.80%', '8.00%', '5.65%', '-', '4.34%', '4.69%'],
 'PRICE': ['97.6802',
  '96.5669',
  '96.21589',
  '95.18761',
  '98.96079',
  '-',
  '99.9888',
  '99.97876']}
)
```

Expected final dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(
{'Date': ['Sep 8, 2022', 'Jun 16, 2022', 'Apr 27, 2022'],
 'Sum SZE(M)': [239.08, 371.45, 433.18],
 'CLASS-A': ['A', 'A', 'A'],
 'CCY-A': ['USD', 'USD', 'USD'],
 'SZE(M)-A': [202.81, 356.0, 405.62],
 'WAL-A': [1.91, 1.05, 2.28],
 'DR-A': ['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA'],
 'PRICE-A': [97.6802, 98.96079, 99.9888],
 'CLASS-B': ['B', 'B', 'B'],
 'CCY-B': ['USD', 'USD', 'USD'],
 'SZE(M)-B': [13.78, 15.45, 27.56],
 'WAL-B': ['-', '3.19', '2.58'],
 'DR-B': ['AA', 'BBB', 'AA'],
 'PRICE-B': ['96.5669', '-', '99.97876'],
 'CLASS-C': ['C', nan, nan],
 'CCY-C': ['USD', nan, nan],
 'SZE(M)-C': [13.39, nan, nan],
 'WAL-C': ['-', nan, nan],
 'DR-C': ['A', nan, nan],
 'PRICE-C': [96.21589, nan, nan],
 'CLASS-D': ['D', nan, nan],
 'CCY-D': ['USD', nan, nan],
 'SZE(M)-D': [9.1, nan, nan],
 'WAL-D': [2.25, nan, nan],
 'DR-D': ['BBB', nan, nan],
 'PRICE-D': [95.18761, nan, nan]})
```

The suffix will be from class columns (A,B,C,D etc) and this will be for all the columns(not all are shown in the example).

Also attaching the images of csvs for clarification:

Initial:

[image]

Final:
[image]

Any guidance in the right direction is appreciated. Thanks.

I tried pivoting the dataframe but I am struggling to find out what to put as columns and values. I am guessing it is either pivot, transpose or melt that is I am looking for, but am a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want to do to get the desired output:

Pivot the df, then sort the columns by level 1, which is A,B,C,.... Then join the multicolumn index to one level in the format you want.

```
out = (
    df
    .pivot(index='Date', 
           columns='CLASS', 
           values=['CCY','SZE(M)','WAL','DR','TYPE', 'BNCH','GDNC', 'SPRD', 'CPN', 'YLD', 'PRICE'])
    .sort_index(axis=1, level=1))

out.columns = out.columns.map('-'.join) #prefer that one over the f-string
# out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f"{x[0]}-{x[1]}")

# create new column for sum of all SZE(M) columns
out.insert(0, 'Sum SZE(M)', out.filter(like='SZE(M)').sum(axis=1))


#additional, if needed
out.index = pd.to_datetime(out.index, format="%d-%b-%y")
out = out.sort_index()

print(out)
```

```
            Sum SZE(M)   BNCH-A CCY-A  CPN-A DR-A   GDNC-A   PRICE-A SPRD-A SZE(M)-A TYPE-A WAL-A  YLD-A   BNCH-B CCY-B  CPN-B DR-B GDNC-B   PRICE-B SPRD-B SZE(M)-B TYPE-B WAL-B  YLD-B   BNCH-C CCY-C  CPN-C DR-C GDNC-C   PRICE-C SPRD-C SZE(M)-C TYPE-C WAL-C  YLD-C   BNCH-D CCY-D  CPN-D DR-D GDNC-D   PRICE-D SPRD-D SZE(M)-D TYPE-D WAL-D  YLD-D
Date                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
2022-04-27      433.18  I-Curve   USD  4.30%  AAA     175a   99.9888    170   405.62  Fixed  2.28  4.34%  I-Curve   USD  4.64%   AA   200a  99.97876    200    27.56  Fixed  2.58  4.69%      NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN       NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN      NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN       NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
2022-06-16      371.45  I-Curve   USD  4.55%  AAA        -  98.96079    275    356.0  Fixed  1.05  5.65%  I-Curve   USD      -  BBB      -         -      -    15.45  Fixed  3.19      -      NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN       NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN      NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN       NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
2022-09-08      239.08  I-Curve   USD  4.30%  AAA  225-235   97.6802    215   202.81  Fixed  1.91  5.65%  I-Curve   USD  4.64%   AA   275a   96.5669    290    13.78  Fixed     -  6.40%  I-Curve   USD  4.89%    A   325a  96.21589    330    13.39  Fixed     -  6.80%  I-Curve   USD  5.53%  BBB   450a  95.18761    450      9.1  Fixed  2.25  8.00%
```

Because of question in the comments. This is what `out` looks like before the line `out.columns = ...`
level=0 is the first row of columns, level=1 ('CLASS') is the second row.

```
              BNCH  CCY    CPN   DR     GDNC     PRICE SPRD  SZE(M)   TYPE   WAL    YLD     BNCH  CCY    CPN   DR  GDNC     PRICE SPRD SZE(M)   TYPE   WAL    YLD     BNCH  CCY    CPN   DR  GDNC     PRICE SPRD SZE(M)   TYPE  WAL    YLD     BNCH  CCY    CPN   DR  GDNC     PRICE SPRD SZE(M)   TYPE   WAL    YLD
CLASS            A    A      A    A        A         A    A       A      A     A      A        B    B      B    B     B         B    B      B      B     B      B        C    C      C    C     C         C    C      C      C    C      C        D    D      D    D     D         D    D      D      D     D      D
Date                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
16-Jun-22  I-Curve  USD  4.55%  AAA        -  98.96079  275   356.0  Fixed  1.05  5.65%  I-Curve  USD      -  BBB     -         -    -  15.45  Fixed  3.19      -      NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN      NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
27-Apr-22  I-Curve  USD  4.30%  AAA     175a   99.9888  170  405.62  Fixed  2.28  4.34%  I-Curve  USD  4.64%   AA  200a  99.97876  200  27.56  Fixed  2.58  4.69%      NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN      NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
8-Sep-22   I-Curve  USD  4.30%  AAA  225-235   97.6802  215  202.81  Fixed  1.91  5.65%  I-Curve  USD  4.64%   AA  275a   96.5669  290  13.78  Fixed     -  6.40%  I-Curve  USD  4.89%    A  325a  96.21589  330  13.39  Fixed    -  6.80%  I-Curve  USD  5.53%  BBB  450a  95.18761  450    9.1  Fixed  2.25  8.00%
```

Comment: 1) In the pivot function I don't specify a level. Sorting along axis 1 (-> columns) on level=1 which is sorting by `CLASS`. After pivot we have a multiindex. level 0 are all columns we specified in pivot in `values` and level 1 are all values in the column `CLASS`. 2) we combine the multiindex. Each column contain a level 0 (`x[0]`) and a level 1 (`x[1]`) name, with the f-string, we combine them to one single column name, seperated by a `-`